# How to keep "N/A" strings in Pandas while dropping blanks with dropna?

Tags: pandas, null, nan

So I have inherited a large dataset, and it contains a large number of entirely blank columns. I am reading this into a Pandas dataframe, and want to drop all the empty columns. At first I tried .dropna, and it worked great, with one problem. The dataset contains a lot of fields that contain "N/A" or "n/a" or "NA", and those are getting caught up in the .dropna sweep. This means I am losing columns that I want to keep, along with the truly empty ones that I want to drop.

I tried reading the file in with ***pd.read_excel(file, keep_default_na=False)***, but that also drops all the columns I want to keep with the "N/A"-type strings.

How can I read this file in without all the  blank cells while keeping all the "N/A" strings, or drop all the blank columns while keeping the "N/A" strings once I have read it in?

Image shows columns I want to keep in red, and columns I want to drop in yellow.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: May be, something like this: pd.read_excel(file, na_values=[' '])

Comment: That worked!  I tried something like that earlier but just had empty quotes [''], not a blank space in between. Thank you!!!!!